# Using keydown() why after first character if alert the value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keydown

If I press (for the first time) a character, than the alert prints an empty value.

How is possible? I don't understand.

```
$('#search-vulc').on('keydown', function() {
  var textinsert = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase();
  alert(textinsert);
});
```

Please tell me how I can print it with the first time, when the character is pressed.

Here is there also a jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/06xg4c78/1/

Comment: keydown event occures before the value is updating, use `keyup` or `input` event instead

Comment: Use console.log to debug, not alert

Comment: @PranavCBalan how kind of form event ? maybe change() ?

Comment: @Borja : which fires when you leave focus in case of text field

Comment: @DharaParmar i read that for all browser is better use "keydown" and not "keyup"... is a bullshit ? :D

Comment: @Borja : it's all depends on your need...

Comment: @PranavCBalan ok thanks a lot for the suggest ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keuyp event:

This is because `keypress events` are fired before the new character is added to the value of the element (so the first `keypress event` is fired before the first character is added, while the value is still empty). You should use `keyup` instead, which is fired after the character has been added.

```
$('#search-vulc').on('keyup', function() {
  var textinsert = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase();
  alert(textinsert);
});
```

Comment: keypress isn't keydown

Comment: @Borja I dont think so, If you want to perform some action before character enter use keydown and If you want to perform some action after character entered use keyup - as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead:

```js
$('#search-vulc').on('keyup', function() {

  var textinsert = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase();
  alert(textinsert);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" size="150" style="width: 150px;" name="qu" id="search-vulc">
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/06xg4c78/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you use `keydown` functions it works before dom gets the input value

Use `keyup` which fires the event when you leave the key so it will get the value entered

```js
$('#search-vulc').on('keyup', function() {
  var textinsert = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase();
  alert(textinsert);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="150" style="width: 150px;" name="qu" id="search-vulc">
```